# Can Ubuntu 16.04 be installed on a Macbook Pro

Tags: dual-boot

Can Ubuntu 16.04 be installed on a Macbook Pro (Retina, 13 inch,early 2015)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hardware compatibility question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. However, it's not as easy as installing it alongside a different Linux or Windows system. Take a look at [this website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) and look for what fits best.

Note that some hardware components or functionality of them (like for example changing the brightness of the screen) might not be supported. You can also find information about this on that website.

Comment: on lenovo with intel it was pretty easy to install ubuntu 16.04 from botable usb on seperate partition alongside windows 10 or 11 (dont know which shit was that exactly)